# Merge a list of comparison pairs into a list of comparison groups

Tags: algorithm, comparison

I want to merge a list of comparison pairs into a single list of merged comparisons, the output list should only have lists whose element at index ***i*** is better than element at index ***i + 1***

---

e.g. let's say I have these list of comparison pairs:

```
[
  [a, b],
  [a, c],
  [a, d],
  [b, c],
  [b, d],
  [c, d]
]
```

because:

1- a is better than b and c and d

2- b is better than c and d

3- c is better than d

therefore I get a simple list

```
[
  [a, b, c, d]
]
```

---

but in case I have this list of comparison pairs:

```
[
  [a, b],
  [a, c],
  [a, d],
  [b, c],
  [c, d]
]
```

N.B. b is not better than d

therefore the output should be

```
[
  [a, b, c],
  [a, c, d]
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: How can `b` not be "better" than `d` if `b` is better than `c` which is better than `d` ?
Aside from that, what does your current code looks like ?